# String join use python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, join

I have a problem to solve.
I can not understand how to modify a list by adding 9000 where necessary. Can you help me?

I have this list:

```
1
2
9007
7
9001
45
67
33
9033
```

final results:

```
9001
9002
9007
9007
9001
9045
9067
9033
9033
```

how do i do it in python 3?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l2=[]
l1 = [1, 2,9007, 7, 9001, 45, 67, 33, 9033]
for item in l1:
    if item>=9000:
        l2.append(item)
    else:
        item = item+9000
        l2.append(item)
    print(l2)
```

Comment: Great ! ...can it also be applied to strings?

Comment: I mean that the list is inside a txt file

Comment: with open("file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    l1 = list(data.split('\n'))